# Search first and last names, order by accuracy of match

Tags: php, mysql, search, sql-like

I am trying to build a simple search on my website (it's a social networking website), and I want to search through all users registered on the site, and return a list of suggestions (which is what this query is for, the suggestions list).

my table that I want to search has the columns: `userID`, `fname`, `lname`.

I want to search through the last 2 columns (the 2 names), and return them in order of how much of the names match the search term.

The first part of the query I would run would be:

```
SELECT userID, fname, lname FROM names WHERE
```

but the rest, I need help with.

**EDIT:**
using this query to search:

```
SELECT userID, fname, lname FROM names WHERE fname LIKE '%".$term."%' OR lname LIKE '%".$term."%'
```

How can I order it so the results are sorted by those that the matches are in the beginning, so when I type `M` it returns say, `Mark` before `adam`

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
SELECT userID, fname, lname,
myRank = CASE WHEN fname = @term THEN 4 
WHEN fname like @term + '%' THEN 3
WHEN fname like '%' + @term + '%' THEN 2
ELSE.... whatever ranking you want
FROM names 
WHERE fname LIKE '%' + @term + '%' 
   OR lname LIKE '%' + @term + '%'
ORDER BY myRank DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using a [full text](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) search for the names.  A full text search will allow you to consider similarity in the match.

Answer (score 0):

something like that:

```
where fname like '%' + @searchterm + '%' or lname like '%' + @searchterm + '%'
```

Comment: Well yes, that would be the first part of it, but the main thing I'm not entirely sure how to do is to order those results by the percentage of match. for example, if the search term is `Steve` and there is a `steve` and `steven`, I would want `steve` to be returned before `steven`

Comment: If you would look at my edited question, that will show some more of what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You could do ORDER BY fname ASC at the end of your query statement (granted that syntax works for your DB statements, it looks like some sort of SQL so there should be something like that that works). This will sort names alphabetically so Steve would show up before Steven (because missing the 'n'). I'm guessing too if you wanted to find something based on the first letter or first couple letters there's probably an equivalent where you could use M* and the asterisk will be your wild card. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just recently ran into a similar problem and used the [Similarity function provided by the Microsoft Master Data Services](http://www.copypastecode.com/39177/). Starting from there I implemented a word based [trigram function](http://ii.nlm.nih.gov/MTI/trigram.shtml). My implementation will match 'Spongebob Squarepants' with 'Squarepants, Bob'.

If you don't own visual studio (which is required to create assemblies used in the sql-server), you could also implement the desired functionality (i.e. fuzzy string matching) using native T-SQL. A nice toolkit can be found [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Puzzles/sql2000dbatoolkitpart3/2363/).

Update: 
Note: Similarity string matching does not work very well with incremental search, i.e. 'M' will not match 'Mark'. You would have to use other attempts, maybe a combination of fuzzy string matching and the classification into 'starts with','contains' etc.